# Correspond Indicator Matrix to Column Names in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, cross-validation

the question I am trying to solve is "How can I create an automated series of code which will pull the desired column header names from a data set to fit a general linearized model (glm)?" I have a data set with 8 variables; however, I only want to use 3 of them to cross validate and find the "best" model. Here's what I've come up with:

```
library(boot)
```

```
salary <- read.csv("salary_data.csv")
vars <- colnames(salary[c(2,3,7)])
nvars <- length(vars)
list.to.expand = vector(mode = "list", length = nvars)
for (i in 1:nvars){
  list.to.expand[[i]]=c(0,1)
}
model.spec.matrix <- expand.grid(list.to.expand)
```

```
vars
model.spec.matrix
```

```
names(model.spec.matrix) <- vars
vars.to.use <- model.spec.matrix[2,]
vars.to.use <- as.numeric(vars.to.use)
cn <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(model.spec.matrix)){
  if(i==1){cn <- colnames(model.spec.matrix[sapply(model.spec.matrix[i,], function(x) x > 0)]) 
  }
}
print(cn)
paste(cn, collapse = "+")
glm.out = glm(paste("LogACG~",paste(cn,collapse = "+"),sep = ""), family = gaussian, data = salary)
cv.err = cv.glm(salary, glm.out, K = 10)$delta[1]
```

My issue lies in the for loop. I've tried to construct a loop which will append the values from "vars" into "model.use", but I cannot seem to get it to read past the 2nd row in the matrix. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I would remove the code I gave you in the answer so that the question and answer still make sense together. The reason you get `character(0)` with the first line is that there are no indicated columns on the first row of your matrix(`0 0 0`) so that's why I had the line after it (`if(length(cn) == 0){cn <- "."}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like several things are going on here.

You've made `LogACG` the explanatory variable in your 2nd-to-last line (`"LogACG~`, but it's also one of the `vars` which ultimately end up in `model.vars` because of `vars <- colnames(salary[c(2,3,7)])`, so that's not right.

Next your 2nd `for` loop should be iterating through the rows of the `model.spec.matrix`, i.e.

`for(i in 1:nrow(model.spec.matrix)){`

and to programmatically capture the column names (variables) indicated by that row you could do

`cn <- colnames(model.spec.matrix[sapply(model.spec.matrix[i,], function(x) x > 0)])`

within the loop. You should also move the `glm` and `cv.glm` inside of the loop.

However, that will overwrite the `glm.out` and `cv.err` each time, so you'll want to create them as empty lists and append the list in each iteration.

So the final product will look like this:

```
# Since you can't use LogACG to explain itself, 
#    suppose you meant to use Engineering as a candidate X
vars <- colnames(salary[c(2,3,8)])

# Make your grid
model.spec.matrix        <- expand.grid(list.to.expand)
names(model.spec.matrix) <- vars

glm.out <- list(rep(NA, nrow(model.spec.matrix)))
cv.err  <- list(rep(NA, nrow(model.spec.matrix)))

for(i in 1:nrow(model.spec.matrix)){
  cn <- colnames(model.spec.matrix[sapply(model.spec.matrix[i,], function(x) x > 0)])
  if(length(cn) == 0){cn <- "."}  
  tmp        <- glm(as.formula(paste("LogACG~",paste(cn,collapse = "+"),sep = "")), family = gaussian, data = salary)
  glm.out[i] <- capture.output(tmp$formula)
}
# > glm.out
# [[1]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ ."
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Rank_Code"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Gender"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Rank_Code + Gender"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Engineering"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Rank_Code + Engineering"
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Gender + Engineering"
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] "LogACG ~ Rank_Code + Gender + Engineering"
```

To get the *entire* model object in the list element, replace

```
glm.out[i] <- capture.output(tmp$formula)
```

with

```
glm.out    <- append(glm.out, tmp)
```

i.e.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(model.spec.matrix)){
  cn <- colnames(model.spec.matrix[sapply(model.spec.matrix[i,], function(x) x > 0)])
  if(length(cn) == 0){cn <- "."}  
  tmp        <- glm(as.formula(paste("LogACG~",paste(cn,collapse = "+"),sep = "")), family = gaussian, data = salary)
  tmp1       <- cv.glm(salary, tmp, K = 10)$delta[1]
  glm.out    <- append(glm.out, tmp)
  cv.err     <- append(cv.err, tmp1)
}

> tail(cv.err)
[[1]]
[1] 2.751025

[[2]]
[1] 2.758954

[[3]]
[1] 2.735063

[[4]]
[1] 2.768075

[[5]]
[1] 2.774433

[[6]]
[1] 2.748291
```

Also, you may be better served to make use of a package like `bestglm` or just the `step` function from the default pacakge `stats` (see `?step`).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you and see how this works. However, I must be able to automate the code so that, if I pull in a dataset of say 100 variables, I can easily pull the ones I want to use and paste them into the glm. The glm function provided would require me to rewrite it every time, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Thank you

Comment: I replaced the model.vars variable with the cn variable you created in your response. When I run the for loop, however, the cn variable returns character(0) when I print it. See my edited code above in the question. Thank you

Comment: so if I wanted to display a plot of the error term from each of the possible models from the above code, how could I do that? I want to determine the minimum error among all models with only main effects (by including and excluding vars according to the model.spec.matrix row with 1's and 0's).

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for all your help, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it. One more thing: so how can I run these models from glm.out through cv.glm and store the error in a vector?

Comment: @bmw3516 No problem. I actually added `cv.err` in my last edit, I was just being lazy before. It's the same process, you just use the `tmp` object within the loop to do the CV, i.e. `tmp1  <- cv.glm(salary, tmp, K = 10)$delta[1]`